# Form validation on keyup with delay

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I am working on setting up some jQuery form validation without a plugin. My desired behavior is to start with the submit button disabled and then validate each input on keyup and then enable the submit button once all fields are valid. There are 4 text inputs and a select box. I want to validate that each of the inputs are not empty, that something is selected in the select box and that the email field contains a valid email address.

I've got it mostly working currently but there is some weirdness with the validation which I think has to do with my `setTimeout` function. The inputs will go back and forth between valid and invalid while typing and sometimes the validation fires too early.

```js
// Form validation
var errors = 0;
$('#contact-form input[name!="submit"], select').on('keyup change', function() {
  var input = $(this);
  var name = input.attr('name');
  var email = $('input#email');
  var email_test = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i;
  var is_email = email_test.test(email.val());
  var not_empty = input.val();
  var empty_inputs = $('#contact-form input[type="text"], select').filter(function() {
    return this.value.length === 0;
  }).length;
  var validate = setTimeout(function() {
    if (name === 'email') {
      if (is_email) {
        input.next().hide();
        input.removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
      } else {
        input.next().show();
        input.removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
      }
    } else {
      if (not_empty) {
        input.removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
        input.next().hide();
      } else {
        input.removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
        input.next().show();
      }
    }
    errors = $('input.error').length;
    if (errors < 1 && empty_inputs === 0) {
      $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',false);
    } else {
      $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',true);
    }
    clearTimeout(validate);
  }, 1500);
});
```

```css
form > div {
  margin-top:20px;
}
form > div:first-child {
  margin-top:0;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  display:block;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
}
  input[type=submit]:disabled {
    background:#ccc;
    color:#fff;
  }
#contact-form input.error, #contact-form select.error {
  border:1px solid #a94442;
}
#contact-form input.valid, #contact-form select.valid {
  border:1px solid #3c763d;
}
#contact-form div.error {
  color:#a94442;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact-form" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
 <div>
        <label for="name">Name *</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <div class="error name">Please enter your name.</div>
    </div>
 <div>
        <label for="city">City *</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" />
        <div class="city error">Please enter your city.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="state">State *</label>
        <select class="state" name="state">
         <option value="" disabled selected>Select your state</option>
   <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
   <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
   <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
   <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
   <option value="CA">California</option>
   <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
   <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
   <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
   <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
   <option value="FL">Florida</option>
   <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
   <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
   <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
   <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
   <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
   <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
   <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
   <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
   <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
   <option value="ME">Maine</option>
   <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
   <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
   <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
   <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
   <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
   <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
   <option value="MT">Montana</option>
   <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
   <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
   <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
   <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
   <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
   <option value="NY">New York</option>
   <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
   <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
   <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
   <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
   <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
   <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
   <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
   <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
   <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
   <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
   <option value="TX">Texas</option>
   <option value="UT">Utah</option>
   <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
   <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
   <option value="WA">Washington</option>
   <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
   <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
   <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
        <div class="state error">Please select your state.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
     <label for="question">Question *</label>
     <input type="text" id="qustion" name="question" />
     <div class="question error">Please enter your question.</div>
 </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email *</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
        <div class="email error">Please enter a valid email address.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="submit">&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ENTER" disabled />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Works clearly with me. You may reduce the delay before checking the inputs (set it to 500 instead of 1500). https://jsfiddle.net/ctdv8qwa/

Comment: It doesn't work though, sometimes while you're typing the input will switch back and forth between valid and invalid and other times the validation will fire too early(right when you tab to it). The timeout should be reset every time someone presses a key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(validate) 
    clearTimeout(validate);
validate = setTimeout(function(){
    // Your validation code
}, 1500);
```

Every time this function call will clear the previous function call, which is waiting to complete timeout.